# os.rename( ) is giving the error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '0.jpg' -> '2.jpg'

Tags: python

I am trying to rename every image file in a folder to names like `1.jpg` , `2.jpg` and so on using Python.
I have written the following code but it is not working and it gives the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '0.jpg' -> '2.jpg'
```

Code:

```
import os
# changing the directory to where the image files are located
os.chdir(r"F:\Images\7 WONDER GARDEN")

for file in os.listdir():
    for num in range(len(os.listdir())):
        os.rename(file, str(num) + ".jpg")
```

I have tried writing the path in `os.rename` but still it is giving the same error.
Please help me to get rid of this problem. 
Thank you for taking the effort to read this question.

Answer (score 2):

You are renaming one single file `len(os.listdir())` times, so the first inner `for` loop iteration will work, but it won't work anymore once the original file is no longer there. Try the following:

```py
import os
# changing the directory to where the image files are located
os.chdir(r"F:\Images\7 WONDER GARDEN")

for index, file in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    os.rename(file, str(index) + ".jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have double loop here, so you're trying to rename first file to `0.jpg`, then to `1.jpg`and so no. Of course, after first rename no more renames are possible. What you really wanted is:

```
for num, file in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    os.rename(file, str(num) + ".jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the double `for` loop is what is causing the problem. The inner `for` loop tries to repeatedly change the name of a file over and over, but once that file's name is changed the first time, it can no longer be found.

The Pythonic solution to this is to use a function called `enumerate()`. `enumerate()` returns a sequence of paired items: an index and an item from the sequence you feed into `enumerate()`.

In our case, the list of file names goes into `enumerate()` and a series of index and filename pairs comes out...

```
(0, a.jpg)
(1, b.jpg)
(2, c.jpg)
```

Applying this to your code... If you use two target variables instead of one in the `for` loop (in this case `num` and `file`, the `for` loop will automagically unpack the values returned by enumerate, a pair at a time and within the `for` loop, you can then use the pairs of values to help with file renaming, as shown below.

```
for num, file in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    os.rename(file, str(num) + ".jpg")
```

Of interest is the fact that enumerate can be set to output values that start from any initial starting point, using a start argument:

```
for pair in enumerate(files, 1000):
```

would end up producing paired values that look like this:

```
(1000, a.jpg)
(1001, b.jpg)
(1002, c.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
num = 0
for file in os.listdir():
    os.rename(file,str(num) + ".jpg")
    num = num+1
```